# How can I get item information in podio

Tags: podio

I am having couple of queries in podio. I want to fetch all the information for items, customer, reference id and type, app id. I am not getting any error for this but i don't have any proper way to fetch all the above points. Please assist me for all the above information. Thanks in advance

I am following podio api documentation for this. I have to implement all this things in ror.

Comment: Please post the queries you have so far so we can point you in the right direction.